# Hankel determinants of symmetric functions

Tags: symmetric-functions, symmetric-groups, determinants

The starting point is that it is known that the Hankel determinants for the Catalan sequence give the number of nested sequences of Dyck paths. I would like to promote this to symmetric functions.
This is motivated by some representation theory.

The naive idea is to start with the sequence of symmetric functions $s_{n,n}$ and take the Hankel determinants using the inner product (that is product in the group ring of $S(2n)$) instead of the usual outer product. However this doesn't make sense.

Take the $2 \times 2$ case. Then the naive determinant is
$$ \left|\begin{array}{cc} s_{n-1,n-1} & s_{n,n} \\\ s_{n,n} & s_{n+1,n+1}\end{array}\right|$$
The inner product of the two diagonal terms is defined but the inner product of the two off-diagonal terms is not.

The idea that I want to test is that this is $\sum_\lambda s_\lambda$ where the sum is over the conjugates of the partitions $4^a2^{n-2a}$.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? If this does get fixed then I would like to know how to calculate the result. The difficulty is that I have not seen an implementation of the inner product in the computer algebra systems I use, Magma and Sage (which I think both use the same source for symmetric functions).

Comment: That would be Hankel.

Comment: There is some standard technique for the Hankel determinants; see Christian Krattenthaler's "Advanced Determinant Calculus" and "Advanced Determinant Calculus: A Compliment" available from the author's page and arXiv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely to obtain for such a determinant the sum of all Schur functions indexed by partitions of $2n$ with four parts all even or all odd. Indeed, this sum is already equal to the inner product $s_{n,n}\ast s_{n,n}$ (see [arXiv:0809.3469](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.3469)).

About your second question: you can compute the inner product of symmetric functions in SAGE using the "kronecker_product" command. For instance, compute the inner product of Schur functions $s_{6,2}\ast s_{5,3}$ as follows:

s=SymmetricFunctionAlgebra(QQ,basis='schur')

s([6,2]).kronecker_product(s([5,3]))

You may also use Maple with John Stembridge's package SF and the command "itensor".

Comment: That's interesting. The answer I "want" is not all four parts even, just the differences. However I didn't know the result you state.

Comment: I copied the description of the expansion from the preprint I gave in reference, but it's the same. "All parts even or all parts odd" also means "all differences even".

Comment: You are right. I have changed the post. There is still a difficulty in that $[2,2,1,1]$ appears in the proposed answer but does not have all parts even or all parts odd.

Comment: The reference you gave appears to attribute the result to:

MR2548921  Garsia, A. ;  Wallach, N. ;  Xin, G. ;  Zabrocki, M.    Hilbert series of invariants, constant terms and Kostka-Foulkes
 polynomials.  
 Discrete Math.  309  (2009),  no. 16, 5206--5230.

However I didn't see it. Have I missed it?

Comment: There is no problem with your link. The reference I have given is [9] in this paper - except there it is called a "preprint". They give this as the reference for $s_{n,n}*s_{n,n}$ but I can't see it. Either I need better glasses or the published paper is different to the preprint.

Comment: I removed my comment. I had not understood your question.

In the paper in Discrete Math, the formula for $s_{n,n} \ast s_{n,n}$ appears in Theorem 4.5. However there they refer to yet another paper.

The same formula has also been derived by Laurent Manivel in arXiv:0809.3710. 